# JSDoc: arrow function params

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc, arrow-functions

I'm trying to document my code with JSDoc (EcmaScript 2015, WebStorm 12 Build 144.3357.8).

I have an arrow function which I want to document its parameters.
This two examples work (I get auto-completion):

```
/** @param {Number} num1*/
var a = num1 => num1 * num1;
//------------------------------
/** @param {Number} num1*/
var a = num1 => {
    return num1 * num1;
};
```

But when I want to document an arrow function in `forEach` function, for example, the auto-completion isn't working (all of the below):

```
/** @param {Number} num1*/
[].forEach(num1 => {
    return num1 * num1;
});
//------------------------------
/** @param {Number} num1*/
[].forEach(num1 => num1 * num1);
//------------------------------
[].forEach(/** @param {Number} num1*/num1 => num1 * num1);
//------------------------------
[].forEach(/** @param {Number} num1*/num1 => {
    return num1 * num1;
});
```

Has anyone managed to get this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting from the next EAP build, WebStorm will understand this:

```
[].forEach(/**Number*/num1 => {
    return num1 * num1;
});
```

Please look at [WEB-19280](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19280) for details.

Comment: I came across this question when looking for vscode solution that's how it's done in vscode 
[].forEach(/** @param {Number} num1*/  num1 => {
....
}

Comment: For VSC you can cast the array to the type you want to get autocompletion in the anonymous function: `(/**@type {Array<number>}*/([])).forEach(num1 => num1 * num1)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this format:

```js
/**
 * @param {(prevState: ActionState) => ActionState} setActionState
 */
function f(setActionState) {
  // ...
}
```

Or:

```js
/**
 * @param {function(prevState: ActionState): ActionState} setActionState
 */
function f(setActionState) {
  // ...
}
```